# Is there a Teamspeak Authentication I can use for my Website?

Tags: authentication, teamspeak

I want to connect the Users from my website with the TeamSpeak server, that i can automatically grant rights, ban users and so on.

At the moment the User has to enter his Ts UID on my website, so that i can search him in the TS database.

But for some time now, you can login to the TeamSpeak client with a TeamSpeak account.

Is there a way that the users can login on my website with this Teamspeak account like with Google, Facebook and so on?

And am I able to find them on my TS Server when they are logged in with that account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeamSpeak's myTeamSpeak system was definitely not designed for any oauth type functions. However TeamSpeak has a brilliant plugin SDK, serverquery and clientquery available to interact with teamspeak.

I would recommend you "link" users' TeamSpeak UID's like https://ts-n.net/ranksystem.php does via a user's IP address. From there you can simply accept the login, or you can take it a step further and sending a message with a "activation code" via one of the ways mentioned above to interact with teamspeak for additional security.

From what I understand, you want to find online user's that are logged in to your website through a form of authentication using teamspeak. I have no idea what you mean by "them", but teamspeak's serverquery lets you search through every single client in it's database, and whatever you are looking for is there or in your logs folder.

Sorry I could not be more helpful, I will edit this/respond when/if you clarify your question.

Comment: Thank you, I just wanted to know if there is a way to autenticate via My TeamSpeak. I've allready implemented a system where the user has to enter his TS uid so that i can use it in my queries.